# Dilation vs dilatation

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, mathematics

I am curious about the usage of words "dilation" and "dilatation" in mathematics. I believe they mean exactly the same thing and wonder which one to choose.

Here is an article on wiki concerning  dilations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilation_(metric_space)

Here is a link to a Khan Academy video on <s>dilatations</s> dilations: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/geometry-home/transformations/dilations-scaling/v/dilating-from-an-arbitrary-point-example

And here is a link to a math paper speaking of dilatation https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102992298

Comment: See [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160496/what-is-the-real-difference-between-dilation-and-dilatation#:~:text=Dilatation%20is%20defined%20as%20a,cross%2Drefer%20to%20one%20another.)

Comment: In maths classes in UK schools, it is spelt "enlargement".

Comment: Thanks for the link Michael! I see now that this is an issue not only in maths. James, thanks for mentioning enlargement. Strictly speaking, dilation in maths can also decrease the size of an object, at least according to its definition, i.e. it is a synonym of "homothety"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation

Comment: Where in the video is the word "dilatations" used?

Comment: @JamesK A dilation can decrease the size.

Comment: In UK schools, so can an "enlargement" if the scale factor is fractional.

Comment: opps, I misread dilating as dilatating (I guess this happened because I googled "math dilatition" and it gave me Khan academy)... You are right Accumulation, thanks. So it looks like one should use dilation?

Comment: Words may have very precisely defined meanings in mathematics  that cannot be determined by looking at their meanings in everyday English usage. For example, the “sandwich theorem” has nothing to do with food. I suggest asking at math stack exchange and saying that you are not a native speaker of English.